# Displaying search results whilst user is typing

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, frontend

This is example [WEBSITE](https://www.flydubai.com/en/)
In this website when user want to select flight and start typing in `FROM` input field then immediately results are displaying underneath this search input field. Can anybody please advise or give me code example as to how its working

Comment: That is called typeahead. Just google.

Answer (score 1):

From the example website, you are looking for a means to make asynchronous requests.
In your front end (JavaScript)

1. Your input field should listen for a change events (e.g. onKeyUp, onKeyDown or onChange)
2. When a change is detected you want to make a request to a server with the search string
3. You want to update the results list with the response from the server (the search results)

Useful Articles;
[1. Introducing asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

[2. Learn JavaScript: Requests](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/fscp-async-javascript-and-http-requests/modules/fecp-learn-javascript-requests/cheatsheet)

[3. Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

[4. Introduction to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)